# How to solve the RuntimeError when using torch.utils.tensorboard to add a graph

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard

I am trying to use tensorboard to visualize my pytorch model and encounter a problem. The input tensor's shape is (-1, 1, 20, 15) and the output tensor's shape is (-1, 6). My model combines a list of 5 convolutional networks.

packages:

- python: 3.7.6
- pytorch: 1.4.0
- tensorboard: 2.1.0

The pytorch model is as below:

```py
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.nn import functional as F
class MyModel(nn.Module):
    """example"""

    def __init__(self, nchunks=[2, 5, 3, 2, 3], resp_size=6):
        super().__init__()
        self.nchunks = nchunks
        self.conv = [nn.Conv2d(1, 2, (2, x)) for x in nchunks]
        self.pool = nn.Sequential(
            nn.AdaptiveMaxPool1d(output_size=10), nn.Flatten(start_dim=1)
        )
        self.bn = nn.BatchNorm1d(100)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(100, 100)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(100, 100)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(100, resp_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        xi = torch.split(x, self.nchunks, dim=3)
        xi = [f(subx.float()).view(-1, 2, 19) for f, subx in zip(self.conv, xi)]
        xi = [self.pool(subx) for subx in xi]
        xi = torch.cat(xi, dim=1)
        xi = self.bn(xi)
        xi = F.relu(self.fc1(xi))
        xi = F.relu(self.fc2(xi))
        xi = self.fc3(xi)
        return xi
```

Here is the code for the tensorboard summary writer:

```py
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
x = torch.rand((5,1,20,15))
model = MyModel()
writer = SummaryWriter('logs')
writer.add_graph(model, x)
```

Such an error is returned:

```
RuntimeError: Cannot insert a Tensor that requires grad as a constant. Consider making it a parameter or input, or detaching the gradient
Tensor:
(1,1,.,.) =
 -0.2108 -0.4986
 -0.4009 -0.1910

(2,1,.,.) =
  0.2383 -0.4147
  0.2642  0.0456
[ torch.FloatTensor{2,1,2,2} ]
```

I guess the model has some issues, but I am not sure what happens.

This similar github [issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/24157) does not relate to my problem because I am not using multi GPUs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by replacing

```py
[nn.Conv2d(1, 2, (2, x)) for x in nchunks]
```

with

```py
nn.ModuleList([nn.Conv2d(1, 2, (2, x)) for x in nchunks])
```